# Openstack.Net SDK cannot access services

Tags: c#, openstack, rackspace-cloud, keystone, openstacknetsdk

We've setup an OpenStack system on our own hardware installing all components, with everything seemingly fine as we've created networks and VMs through the web interface.

I'm trying to use openstack.net SDK to do things programatically. I seem to be able to Authenticate fine using a username and password, but when it comes to accessing other services that are installed, we get errors suggesting the API endpoints aren't available to the user.

The code we're using is below which works fine until the CreateServer line at which point I get the error

"Unable to authenticate user and retrieve authorized service endpoints."

```
 Uri baseUrl = new Uri("http://mycloudip:5000/v2.0");
 CloudIdentity cloudId = new CloudIdentity()
            {
                Username = userName,
                Password = password
            };
 CloudIdentityProvider cip = new CloudIdentityProvider(cloudId, baseUrl);
 UserAccess ua = cip.Authenticate(cloudId);

 CloudServersProvider provider = new CloudServersProvider(cloudId);

 Metadata metaData = new Metadata(); // Add some metadata just because we can
 metaData.Add("Description", "Example 4 - Getting Started");

 string serverName = "Example4";
 string imageId = "48df4181-040e-4821-8723-d9e4ba908d2f";
 string flavorId = "3";

NewServer newServer = provider.CreateServer(serverName, imageId, flavorId, DiskConfiguration.Manual, metaData);
```

I can see all the service urls in the Access and Security >> API Endpoints section whilst logged on as the same user in the dashboard, but UserAccess.ServiceCatalog doesn't seem to be populated with anything.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `IIdentityProvider` used by the `CloudServersProvider` implementation in openstack.net SDK 1.3.2.0 is designed around the authentication requirements for Rackspace. In order to authenticate against a different OpenStack-compatible installation, you'll need to follow the steps described in the following documentation:

[OpenStack Authentication (openstack.net API Reference Documentation)](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/html/1bb35d97-0c79-4e98-a2ae-6c1eef098ba7.htm)

The following is an excerpt of the current documentation:

> This page describes the process for authenticating against reference OpenStack installations, including but not limited to DevStack and the Rackspace Private Cloud.
>
> ### Usage Notes
>
> Client authentication against a reference OpenStack installation requires the following.
>
> Create an instance of `CloudIdentityWithProject` and initialize its properties with the desired authentication credentials. The `CloudIdentityWithProject` credentials class allows the `tenantName` and `tenantId` properties described in the OpenStack documentation to be defined.
>
> Create an instance of `OpenStackIdentityProvider`, and pass the previously created credentials to the constructor.
>
> When creating a service provider instance, such as `CloudFilesProvider` or `CloudQueuesProvider`, pass **null** for the `CloudIdentity` parameter and the identity provider from the previous step as the `IIdentityProvider` parameter.
>
> ### Limitations
>
> The `OpenStackIdentityProvider` only supports authentication using username and password credentials, along with optionally specifying the tenant name and/or tenant ID (referred to as the project name and ID starting with the Identity Service API v3).

Comment: Thanks, that's pointed me in the right direction. ServiceCatalog now has multiple items in all with 'regionOne', however I now get 'The user does not have access to the requested service or region' when I make a call to ListContainers(region: "regionOne").

Comment: Created here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307286/openstack-net-sdk-cannot-access-service-with-region

Comment: Does the fact that your request for me to put that in another question has disappeared, mean you've got nothing more to add?

Comment: Thanks. Discovered the issue which I put in comment of the other question, not sure the best way around it yet though.