# Openstack authorization

Tags: c#, openstack

Hello to everyone reading this,

I want to list all images from openstack with the following code in C#:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace;
using net.openstack.Core.Domain;
using net.openstack.Core.Providers;
namespace RepositoriesTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class RackspaceTests
    {
        public string username = "mbar";
        public string password = "password";
        public string url = "http://192.168.5.55:5001/v3";
        public string project_id = "a9b2b59f093f44d881b8ebccbba00901";
        public string project_name = "test-nsix";
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            var identity = new CloudIdentityWithProject()
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password,
                ProjectId = new ProjectId(project_id),
                ProjectName = project_name
            };
            var identityProvider = new OpenStackIdentityProvider(new Uri(url));


            var serverProvider = new CloudServersProvider(identity, identityProvider);

            var images = serverProvider.ListImages(region: "RegionOne");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
}
```

When I run this example I receive the following error: **The request you have made requires authentication.**
I checked in the browser window what I get from url: http://192.168.5.55:5001/v3 and I see that server exists:

```
{"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2016-04-04T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}], "id": "v3.6", "links": [{"href": "http://192.168.5.55:5001/v3/", "rel": "self"}]}}
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies and why I can not authorize.

This is stacktrace:

```
   w net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.Validators.HttpResponseCodeValidator.Validate(Response response) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Providers\Rackspace\Validators\HttpResponseCodeValidator.cs:wiersz 48
   w net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.CheckResponse(Response response) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Providers\Rackspace\ProviderBase`1.cs:wiersz 861
   w net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.ExecuteRESTRequest[T](CloudIdentity identity, Uri absoluteUri, HttpMethod method, Object body, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameter, Dictionary`2 headers, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isTokenRequest, RequestSettings requestSettings, Func`7 callback) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Providers\Rackspace\ProviderBase`1.cs:wiersz 505
   w net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.ProviderBase`1.ExecuteRESTRequest[T](CloudIdentity identity, Uri absoluteUri, HttpMethod method, Object body, Dictionary`2 queryStringParameter, Dictionary`2 headers, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isTokenRequest, RequestSettings settings) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Providers\Rackspace\ProviderBase`1.cs:wiersz 294
   w net.openstack.Core.Providers.OpenStackIdentityProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetUserAccess>b__0() w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Core\Providers\OpenStackIdentityProvider.cs:wiersz 108
   w net.openstack.Core.Caching.UserAccessCache.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Get>b__0(String k) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Core\Caching\UserAccessCache.cs:wiersz 58
   w System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
   w net.openstack.Core.Caching.UserAccessCache.Get(String key, Func`1 refreshCallback, Boolean forceCacheRefresh) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Core\Caching\UserAccessCache.cs:wiersz 58
   w net.openstack.Core.Providers.OpenStackIdentityProvider.GetUserAccess(CloudIdentity identity, Boolean forceCacheRefresh) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Core\Providers\OpenStackIdentityProvider.cs:wiersz 123
   w net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace.CloudIdentityProvider.Authenticate(CloudIdentity identity) w C:\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\OSTK-NET19-BLD\src\corelib\Providers\Rackspace\CloudIdentityProvider.cs:wiersz 948
   w RepositoriesTests.RackspaceTests.TestConnection() w D:\Projekty\NSIX\RepositoriesTests\RackspaceTests.cs:wiersz 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass to identityProvider the CloudIdentityWithProject object:

```
var identityProvider = new OpenStackIdentityProvider(new Uri(url), projectCloudId);
```

Comment: What is projectCloudId? OpenStackIdentityProvider has no constructor which takes such parameter.

Comment: identity -> projectCloudId

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307286/openstack-net-sdk-cannot-access-service-with-region

Comment: I did as you said , but the error is still the same .